# Determine whether event is defaultPrevented in external delegate call

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

Given the two jQuery functions bound to an element directly and via delegation.

```
$("a").on("click", function (e) {
    console.log(e.isDefaultPrevented()); // returns false.
    // TODO: Determine whether the other function isDefaultPrevented.
});

$("body").on("click", "a", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("I am a delegated call");
});
```

How would I determine in the directly bound function whether `e.preventDefault();` has been called in the delegated function?

Theoretically I could traverse up the DOM and check any bound event handlers using `$._data()` and by parsing the function as a string using `/preventDefault\(\)/.test(handler)` but that would be very unwise since it would both be expensive and `$._data()` is also marked for depreciation in favour of a private `data_priv` variable.

Any ideas?

Comment: Having two of the same event delegations on the same element is redundant and going to cause issues. Is there some reason you can't have the logic under one `on` method? Or make the selectors more specific so they're not picking up the same elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I determine in the directly bound function whether `e.preventDefault();` has been called in the delegated function?

You *can't*, because the delegated function hasn't been called yet. Your direct handler will always be called before a delegated handler that matches the same element, because the delegated handler doesn't run until the event bubbles to it, which is *after* the direct handlers have had a go at it.

If you have control over both handlers, then of course you can set up communication between them:

```
(function() {
    $("a").on("click", function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);

        // Direct handler is always called first
        $this.data("prevented", false);
        setTimeout(function() {
            if ($this.data("prevented")) {
                // Prevented by delegated handler
            }
        }, 0);
    });

    $("body").on("click", "a", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).data("prevent", true);
    });
})();
```

But of course, by that time it's too late to prevent it in the direct handler if you wanted to.

Example:

```js
$("#container div").on("click", function(e) {
  snippet.log("direct called");
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.data("prevent", false);
  setTimeout(function() {
    if ($this.data("prevent")) {
      snippet.log("direct detected default prevented");
    } else {
      snippet.log("direct detected default NOT prevented");
    }
  }, 0);
});
$("#container").on("click", "div", function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  snippet.log("delegated called");
  if ($this.hasClass("prevent")) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $this.data("prevent", true);
    snippet.log("delegated prevented default");
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="prevent">
    Click me and the delegated handler will prevent the default.
  </div>
  <div>
    Click me and the delegated handler <strong>won't</strong>
    prevent the default.
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

If you don't, get it gets trickier. You could use `setTimeout` to wait until after the delegated handler runs to check, but then you'd have to check `e.originalEvent`, not just `e`, which brings in cross-browser issues:

```
$("a").on("click", function (e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (e.originalEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            // Yes, the delegated handler prevented it
        }
    }, 0);
});
```

...because the `e` object in the delegated handler isn't the same one as the `e` object in the direct handler; jQuery creates separate ones (using the same underlying original event).

You can work around those cross-browser issues, of course; checking for `e.originalEvent.isDefaultPrevented` and using it if there, and if not looking at `e.originalEvent.returnValue` (the IE-specific thing)...

It's still to late to prevent it in the direct handler if you needed to, though.

Example:

```js
$("#container div").on("click", function(e) {
  snippet.log("direct called");
  setTimeout(function() {
    // Cross-browser issue here
    if (e.originalEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) {
      snippet.log("direct detected default prevented");
    } else {
      snippet.log("direct detected default NOT prevented");
    }
  }, 0);
});
$("#container").on("click", "div", function(e) {
  snippet.log("delegated called");
  if ($(this).hasClass("prevent")) {
    e.preventDefault();
    snippet.log("delegated prevented default");
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="prevent">
    Click me and the delegated handler will prevent the default.
  </div>
  <div>
    Click me and the delegated handler <strong>won't</strong>
    prevent the default.
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. That's wonderfully informative, I appreciate the effort.